# Prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\int_0^1\ln^n(x)dx} = \frac{1}{e}-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Ok, that's really not an easy question to convey in text. What I'm asking is this:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\int_0^1\ln^n (x)dx} = \frac{1}{e}-1$$

Numerically, I'm pretty sure it does (it's about -0.63212). But, I have no idea how I'd go about proving it.

Any insights?

Comment: Hint: With the change of integration variable $x=e^{-t}$ and the Euler integral, $$
\int_0^1 {\log ^n xdx}  = ( - 1)^n \int_0^{ + \infty } {t^n e^{ - t} dt}  = ( - 1)^n n!.
$$

Comment: You're welcome to use equations (albeit display-line ones) in the title too.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: by the change of variable $\ln x=-u$,

$$\int_0^1\ln^n(x)dx=\int_{\infty}^0 -(-u)^n\exp(u)du=(-1)^n\int_0^\infty u^n\exp(-u)du=(-1)^n\Gamma(n+1)=(-1)^nn!$$

Answer (score 5):

Note

$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln^nx dx = \frac{d^n}{da^n}\left(\int_{0}^{1} x^a dx\right)\bigg|_{a=0}
= \frac{d^n}{da^n}\left(\frac1{a+1}\right) \bigg|_{a=0} =(-1)^{n}n!
$$

Thus
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\int\limits_0^1 \ln^nx  dx} = 
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}
=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}-1=
e^{-1}-1$$

Comment: how is your first statement true? with the nth derivative of the integral

Comment: @Reneo - note $$\frac{d}{da}x^a=x^a\ln x$$